# Dictionary API or Library

Tags: ruby, api, dictionary

Does anyone know of a good dictionary API or ruby library to lookup the definitions of words?

I'm thinking it should work something like:

1. I call get_definition(word)
2. It returns the definition for that word (ideally in some way to easily format the definition for display.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ruby-WordNet](http://www.deveiate.org/projects/Ruby-WordNet/) sounds like it does what you're looking for:

> Ruby-WordNet is a Ruby interface to
>   the WordNet® Lexical Database. WordNet
>   is an online lexical reference system
>   whose design is inspired by current
>   psycholinguistic theories of human
>   lexical memory. English nouns, verbs,
>   adjectives and adverbs are organized
>   into synonym sets, each representing
>   one underlying lexical concept.
>   Different relations link the synonym
>   sets.

Comment: Fair warning, this library takes forever to install and set up.  The conversion process is very slow.

Comment: @BobAman did it finish yet? (you said it took forever)

Answer (score 16):

Wordnik.com has several word-info APIs, including a definitions API. More info is here: http://developer.wordnik.com/

[I work for Wordnik. We will have more APIs soon, let us know what you want!]

Comment: This looks very comprehensive - it would be nice to have further return data types please, esp JSON callback! :)

Comment: or a working iPhone example. With so many classes it's a pain to figure out what calls what

Comment: Wordnik seems very good!I just started implementing a .NET api for it

Answer (score 14):

I discovered a webservice for this yesterday.

Go to the [British Council](http://www.britishcouncil.org/new/) homepage and double click on any word (that isn't already a hyperlink).

This should open a popup window with a Cambridge Dictionary definition in it. The API is relatively simple (and *it is* a public API, I checked it yesterday):

```
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/learnenglish/results.asp?searchword=SEARCH_PHRASE&dict=L
```

For reference, here's the code they use to launch this on double-click:

```
/* BC double-click pop-up dictionary */
var NS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape" || navigator.product == 'Gecko') ? 1 : 0;
if (NS) document.captureEvents(Event.DBLCLICK);
document.ondblclick = dict;
var dictvar;

function dict() {
    if (NS) {
        t = document.getSelection();
        pass_to_dictionary(t);
    } else {
        t = document.selection.createRange();
        if(document.selection.type == 'Text' && t.text != '') {
            document.selection.empty();
            pass_to_dictionary(t.text);
        }
    }
}

function pass_to_dictionary(text) {
    //alert(text);
    if (text > '') {
        window.open('http://dictionary.cambridge.org/learnenglish/results.asp?searchword='+text+ '&dict=L', 'dict_win', 'width=650,height=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    }
}
```

Comment: This service seems to no longer be available in the form described by the answer author.

Answer (score 1):

there's also wrappers for dictionary.com's API (a few years old)

http://rubyforge.org/snippet/detail.php?type=snippet&id=53

http://rubyforge.org/snippet/detail.php?type=snippet&id=52

and wiktionary

http://eightpence.com/ninjawords-a-fast-online-dictionary-fast-like-a-ninja/