# Simplest method to get the dictionary definitions of a list of words in a text file

Tags: linux, unix, dictionary, awk, cat

File1:

```
hello
world
```

I don't know the best method to extract a list of words from a text file, find their definitions and paste them into an output textfile. I've been thinking of using WordNet - but don't know how to automate the process.

Does anyone have any ideas (perhaps google/APIs/linux applications) that one could use to find the definitions of words with, and then paste them into a text file?

File2:

```
an expression of greeting; "every morning they exchanged polite hellos" 
universe: everything that exists anywhere; "they study the evolution of the universe"; "the biggest tree in existence"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although an API or library is probably the way to go ([here](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=wordnet&mode=all)'s some Perl stuff), the Bash script below, which is **very** rough might give you some ideas:

```
saveIFS="$IFS"
for w in hello goodbye bicycle world
do
    echo
    echo "------- $w -------"
    def=$(wn $w -over)
    IFS=$'\n'
    for line in $def
    do
        echo -e "\t${line}"
        IFS="$saveIFS"
        if [[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]]*\. ]]
        then 
            for word in $line
            do
                echo -e "\t\t${word%*[,;]}"
            done
        fi
    done
    IFS="$saveIFS"
done
```

If you have a list of words in a file, one word to a line, change the first `for` and last `done` lines of the script above to:

```
while read -r w
    # . . .
done < wordlist
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Dictionary API or Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216612/dictionary-api-or-library) for several solutions.