# How can we have a dictionary service in android apps?

Tags: android, dictionary

Is there any API available for dictionary service for android like that of Maps, Weather,etc.?
How we can have a dictionary service in android apps?

Comment: I meant to ask about a web service, just like what android has for language translation i.e. Google Translate.

Comment: Have you read this comment about Wordnik API:

"Comment 144 by jamesgpainter, Jan 19, 2010
I want it too. In the meantime, I'm using Wordnik's free dictionary API. C'mon Google, 
you're falling behind!"

I visited their site http://docs.wordnik.com/api. I like to know how  to use their API for android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary).  This apparently due to [licensing agreements with the content providers](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html) rather than technical reasons.  There is an [enhancement request open for this](http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=16) which you could monitor.

You could have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216612/dictionary-api-or-library), it asking for Ruby APIs but some of the APIs given are web based and could easily be used from an Android application.

Comment: So how come there are so many apps there on the android market for dictionary and word meaning lookup e.g. http://dictionary.reference.com/apps/android. What these developers are using as an alternate? Whats the solution?

Comment: If you look at the question I linked to there are some Dictionary APIs given there.  I'm assuming the Dictionary.com app is using the Dictionary.com API which is available to "partners": http://techcrunch.com/2009/10/12/dictionary-com-launches-free-blackberry-app-unveils-api/

Comment: Have you read this comment about Wordnik API:

"Comment 144 by jamesgpainter, Jan 19, 2010
I want it too. In the meantime, I'm using Wordnik's free dictionary API. C'mon Google, 
you're falling behind!"

I visited their site http://docs.wordnik.com/api. I like to know how  to use their API for android.