# Android : To Find Meaning for the word

Tags: android

i want to find meaning for the English word. For that what can I do in android? any predefined db is using inside android for finding the meaning for the word

Comment: Surely a grammar checker would be most useful too...

Comment: you should elaborate more about what you really wanna do, because it is very hard to help you with these few keywords

Comment: hi banza i have an idea to develop an app for finding meaning for the words. this how can be done in android? what api can use for maintaining dictionary

Comment: [SO] is not really there for doing your research for you.  This is what google is for ;)

Comment: Also you should use the search facility http://stackoverflow.com/q/2332500/808940

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/WordWidget.java) uses wiktionary.

There is no predefined db.