# Is there a dictionary API for Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an android application in which I have to display the meaning of a word when selected. Just like how Kindle does. From what I understand, there is no google API for this yet (https://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=16)

Could you please let me know if there is a way to achieve this! Also I would like to know how Kindle Dictionary works!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we have a dictionary service in android apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332500/how-can-we-have-a-dictionary-service-in-android-apps)

Comment: I would like to also understand how Kindle does it!